# How to override the default error message for int using FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluentvalidation

I have a problem with overriding the default error message when validating an `InputNumber`. When the field is empty, I get the following message:

> "The field FieldName must be a number.".

The documentation says you should call `WithMessage` on a validator definition. I tried calling `WithMessage` on `NotEmpty` and `NotNull` as shown below but it doesn't change the default message and I didn't see any other method that could check if the field is a number.

```cs
RuleFor(model => model.FieldName)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage("empty")
    .NotNull()
    .WithMessage("null");
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [See my working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UTlkiJ)

Comment: `"When the field is empty"` if its a `int` how it remain empty, does `InputNumber`a allowing null value as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a problem with overriding the default error message when
> validating an InputNumber. When the field is empty, I get the
> following message:

Well, let's consider few things in regards of `int`. It shouldn't allow empty value if you define data-type as `int`. Thus, in case of `InputNumber` we have no logical ground for `.NotEmpty()`.

***Logic: 1:*** Either, we should check if it is a `null` only when we would allow null value. For isntance:

`public int? InputNumber { get; set; }`

So we can handle as below:

```
.NotNull()
.WithMessage("Null Is not accepted")
```

***Logic: 2:*** Or we can check if the `InputNumber` is valid input. In this scenario we can do something like:

```
 .GreaterThan(0)
 .WithMessage("InputNumber must be greater than 0.");
```

Complete Scenario For An int? InputNumber:

```
public class OverrideDefaultErrorMessageForInt : AbstractValidator<User>
    {
        public OverrideDefaultErrorMessageForInt()
        {
        
                 RuleFor(x => x.InputNumber)
                .NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Null Is not accepted")
                .GreaterThan(0)
                .WithMessage("InputNumber must be greater than 0.");
              
                
                                                                   
        }
        
    }
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The messages specified with `WithMessage()` are only used when the preceding validation fails, in your case `NotEmpty()` and `NotNull()`.

The error your are receiving `"The field FieldName must be a number."` indicated that the value received is not a number while the property `FieldName` is a numeric type.